# Lambda Calculus and arithmetic hierarchy

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus

Can lambda calculus be used to define classes $\Sigma_n$ in the arithmetic hierarchy? What I'm looking, in particular, is if lambda calculus can be used for studying limit computability.

Comment: $\lambda$-calculus expresses how to write functions, and sure Church numerals are a functional way to get natural numbers, but $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ would seem more natural with dependent type theory (to get quantifiers and hierarchies) than simply $\lambda$-calc. Do you really intend only to use untyped $\lambda$-calculus or is that a stand in for a broader range of tools in your question?